# How to use shell command to check SVN check-out files and create links in an directory

Tags: bash, svn

Basically my question is how to use bash shell command to do following automatically, so I can track modified files easily.

1. list svn check-out files
2. create link files to above files in an directory called "change"

---

```
laptop$ svn status -q

M            rcms/src/config/ta_show.c
M            rcms/src/config/ta_config.c

laptop$ cd  change
laptop$ link -s ../rcms/src/config/ta_show.c ta_show.c
laptop$ link -s ../rcms/src/config/ta_config.c ta_config.c

laptop$ ls
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Nov 27 12:24 ta_show.c -> ../rcms/src/config/ta_show.c
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Nov 27 12:24 ta_config.c -> ../rcms/src/config/ta_config.c
```

I am thinking to use shell command like below:

```
$ svn status -q | sed 's/M       //' | xargs -I xxx ln -s ***BETWEEN REAL FILE AND BASE FILENAME***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two things need to be concerned:

- the empty line between each file with svn status 'M'
- extract the file name

the awk one liner could do it:

```
awk '$0{x=$2;gsub(".*/","",x);print "ln -s ../"$2" "x}'
```

so if you pipe your `svn status` output to the line above, it print the `ln -s` command lines for you.

if you want the ln -s lines to get executed, you could either pipe the output to sh (`svn status|awk ...|sh`) or replace the `print` with `system`

at the end i would like to show the output below as an exmple:

```
kent$ echo "M            rcms/src/config/ta_show.c

M            rcms/src/config/ta_config.c"|awk '$0{x=$2;gsub(".*/","",x);print "ln -s .."$2" "x}'
ln -s ../rcms/src/config/ta_show.c ta_show.c
ln -s ../rcms/src/config/ta_config.c ta_config.c
```

Comment: Awesome! it works for me. Now I can put all my modified files in one directory. Thank you, Kent!

Comment: @YanX you could upvote my answer and accept it to thank me. ^_*

Comment: I tried that before. However I don't have enough reputation yet (at least 15). I will do that later, definitely. Again, thanks for help.